# AngularJS/AngularUI: Datepicker to only show years?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using AngularUI with AngularJS, and I was wondering if there was a way to just see the year calendar with the Datepicker, not giving them the option to choose month and day.  I tried looking at the documentation and on the js file itself but it doesn't seem like it's possible.  Does anyone have any experience with this?

This is the documentation that I looked at (for the Datepicker):
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Have this requirement too.. :(

Comment: I don't think it is available at this time. As I am sure you saw, you can navigate to the year view, but not view/select only a year. However, you can select only the year for your ng-model (but the user sees the month/day) by setting  datepicker-popup="yyyy". I am sure they would appreciate the contribution: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js :)

Answer (score 5):

You can set the min-mode to 'year' and format the date to be yyyy

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yyyy',
    startingDay: 1,
    minMode: 'year'
};
```

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/0SPMYQ6ND7AOfZwDAFB8?p=preview